# R indexing of xts with unspaced time interval for HFT (follow up on Display time index hint)

Tags: r, xts

Joshua,

I hope you do not find this to be a layman approach but when I tried to implement your hint how to display only certain time index on my xts object i always get blank figures.

```
> dput(x)
structure(c("BHP", "BHP", "BHP", "BHP", "BHP", "BHP", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "44560", "44560.0313951103", "44551.6606603345", 
"44560", "44560", "44560", "39844", "1072460", "405128", "4911", 
"2782", "1632", "44570", "44573.2273632603", "44579.8960524827", 
"44577.1033732318", "44579.9904979095", "44574.9768058317", "80", 
"13054", "88410", "13785", "5262", "1509", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "12", "12"), .indexCLASS = structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate"),
.indexTZ = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1306922412,
1306922414, 1306922415, 1306922416, 1306922417, 1306922418), tzone = "",
tclass = structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate")), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = 
list(NULL, c("SYMBOL", "EX", "BID", "BIDSIZ", "OFR", "OFRSIZ","MODE")))
> x["T10:00:14/T10:00:17"]
     SYMBOL EX BID BIDSIZ OFR OFRSIZ MODE
```

So I get no values though the values are clearly there, what am I missing?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the the output from `dput(mxtsobject)` so we can replicate exactly what you're working with?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you are creating the xts object, but I think it is a small bug in how xts is creating the object - it is not adding in the TZ from the timeDate object.

Try:

```
 indexTZ(x) <- "GMT"

 x['20110601 10:00:14/20110601 10:00:17']
                SYMBOL EX  BID                BIDSIZ    OFR               
 2011-06-01 10:00:14 "BHP"  "N" "44560.0313951103" "1072460" "44573.2273632603"
 2011-06-01 10:00:15 "BHP"  "N" "44551.6606603345" "405128"  "44579.8960524827"
 2011-06-01 10:00:16 "BHP"  "N" "44560"            "4911"    "44577.1033732318"
 2011-06-01 10:00:17 "BHP"  "N" "44560"            "2782"    "44579.9904979095"
                OFRSIZ  MODE
 2011-06-01 10:00:14 "13054" "12"
 2011-06-01 10:00:15 "88410" "12"
 2011-06-01 10:00:16 "13785" "12"
 2011-06-01 10:00:17 "5262"  "12"
```

HTH
Jeff

w.r.t. the bug - I'll look into and patch.  Thanks.

Comment: Patched as of rev 594 on R-forge

Comment: Thanks Jeff and Josh, would never occur to me to look into TZ issue

Answer (score 0):

```
> x[ with(as.POSIXlt(index(x)), ( sec >= 14)) & with(as.POSIXlt(index(x)), ( sec <= 16) ), ]

                    SYMBOL EX  BID                BIDSIZ    OFR               
2011-06-01 10:00:14 "BHP"  "N" "44560.0313951103" "1072460" "44573.2273632603"
2011-06-01 10:00:15 "BHP"  "N" "44551.6606603345" "405128"  "44579.8960524827"
2011-06-01 10:00:16 "BHP"  "N" "44560"            "4911"    "44577.1033732318"
                    OFRSIZ  MODE
2011-06-01 10:00:14 "13054" "12"
2011-06-01 10:00:15 "88410" "12"
2011-06-01 10:00:16 "13785" "12"
```

I could not get the form described in ?"[.xts" to work when being used at the seconds-level of specification, but I see that Jeff R has arrived on the scene and demonstrated that the `indexTZ(x) <- "GMT"` maneuver (not referenced from any of many the help pages I looked at, is necessary.

Comment: Not necessary, more like a workaround for the bug.  Which incidentally is now patched on R-forge - rev 594.

Comment: Version: 0.8-1.2 | Last change: 2011-05-11 06:20:56+02 | Rev.: 593 Does it take 24hours before its available to broader audience.https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118